# Getting values from multiple onEdit() triggers

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know this question might sound wierd. But i am a noob to google sheets and trigger operations.Here's the problem, Lets say I have two cols in a sheet **col_Link and col_value**. col_link contains a link to another sheet and second one is obvious. I have to get the value from the col_link first and perform some operations then while performing second operation I still need this col_Link's link.
Now i have a installed onEdit() trigger which performs this operation but Im stuck on this little thing.
Code:

```
var c = e.range.getColumn();
var r = e.range.getRow();
var val = e.range.getValue();

if (c==1){

  Link_operation(val,row,col);    // this val contains link.
}
else if(c==2){
 Value_operation(link,val,row,col); 
    // here val is some value. I want this function to somehow also has the link from col_Link.
}
```

Since the value can only contain either the link or the value.
What should be my approach to get this? Should I change the way I'm approaching this problem or is it possible to achieve multiple values like this?
Will appreciate any help.

Comment: `range.offset` and getValue() ?

Comment: I dont think offset can help in getting multiple values from onEdit() @TheMaster

Comment: Why not? `e.range`  belongs to Class `range`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little vague and probably should include a screenshot or better detail of what exactly is your expected outcome.

If you want to get multiple values from an `onEdit(e)` trigger that weren't in the edited range then as master suggested, offsetting is the way to do it.

```
function onEdit(e) {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

    var c = e.range.getColumn();
    var r = e.range.getRow();
    var val = e.range.getValue();

    var link = sheet.getRange(r, c - 1).getValue();
    Logger.log(link);

}
```

In this example if the cell B6 is edited then the value in A6 will be logged.

[image]

Comment: Thanx for the idea and now I realised how stupid was my question. Cheers!

Comment: @JustCurious no problem, please consider accepting my answer by clicking on the green tick if you found it answered your question.